# For 'model_object' in 'query_set_list' is showing empty. Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm getting started with Django and I'm having some trouble with query_sets and for loops.

I have created a model and populated my DB with a few entries. In my views.py I have sent a count of these entries to my template and can see the result in HTML.

However when I send a query_set list of these entries I cannot seem to access them and I am unsure as to why.

Here is the view.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from website.models import Member
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    """ View for the homepage of the site """
    num_mem = Member.objects.count()
    mem_list = list(Member.objects.all())
    context = {
            'mem_list': mem_list,
            'num_mem' : num_mem,
    }

    #render the HTML template index.html with the data
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

In index.html I attempt to access these as such.

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {{ num_mem }}
    {% for member in mem_list %}
        There are Members!
    {% empty %}
        Sorry can't find the members =/
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The result returned is as shown.

"6 Sorry can't find the members =/"

So I can see the num_mem value and can see that there are currently 6 values there.

The intention would be to loop through the members list and do something with each value e.g

```
<a href='{{member.m_name.contact_email}}'> Contact {{member.m_name}} here...</a>
```

*edit:I have changed the mem_list as advised however this has not resolved the issues sadly.*

**Updated code.**

```
mem_list = Member.objects.all()
```

I am using Django 1.11 and Python 2.7.5, thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not convert the Member.objects.all to a list. It must return a QuerySet not a list.

So remove the list from

`mem_list = list(Member.objects.all())`

and it must be

`mem_list = Member.objects.all()`

Comment: Hi Vineeth, I have tried that again there but unfortunately it hasn't worked.
Not sure why neither has worked as Django's documentation seems to indicate it should

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the error and let you know :)

Comment: Hello Cian, I tried to reproduce the error but for me it worked just fine. Why don't you try updating django ? The latest version is 2.1 right now.

Comment: Hi Vineeth, I resolved the issue, there was a naming issue on the mem_list. Think it could have been from copy pasting. Rewriting the code resolved the issue alongside your clarification. As such I'll mark this as the resolving answer. Thanks again!